# Add source file to Autottol project

Tags: c, eclipse, autotools, eclipse-cdt

I'm fighting with eclipse and autotools project.
I'What I'm trying to find is a way to add includes dirs and new source files to project.

So far I modified in `/src/makefile` of my project:

1. `DEFAULT_INCLUDES` to add all includes directories
2. `My_Project_CFLAGS` to add used libs

The problem is that each time I have to reconfigure the project (by project popup menu) The maakefile is restored at original, loosing all my changes.

Is in Eclipse IDE a way in project properties where I can add my changes that grants all my modifications are applied to the project after a reconfigure project command?

Or Am I wrong modifing manually makefile and the right way to do this stuff is....?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are really using autotools, you should edit Makefile.am instead of Makefile.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use makefile, but I can show you how to add a specific folder (which can include many other folders).

First, you need to put your folder in the project folder (in your pc). Then you need to click on the `Package Explorer` and hit `F5` (to refresh it) and you will see your `folder` in the `Package Explorer`.

Now you need to add it to the Build Path: You click **right click** on the `folder name -> Build Path - > Use as Source Folder`